# Django passing Polish characters to Angular in init causes lexer error

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

Here's the problem - I would like to pass from Django to Angular data using init. I would do that in the following way:

```
<div ng-init="supervisor={{supervision.supervisor}}">
```

Which seems fine, right? However, it fails once the variable `{{supervision.supervisor}}`contains characters like 'ż' with `Lexer Error: Unexpected next character`.

Is there a smart way to deal with the problem on Django side without the need to wider the range of characters allowed in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the value in quotes.

```
<div ng-init="supervisor='{{supervision.supervisor}}'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

I've added a function to the controller scope:

```
$scope.initialize = function(data){
    $scope.supervisor = data;
};
```

and then I did this in my html template:

```
ng-init="initialize( '{{supervision.supervisor}}');
```

And now it works. Hope it help you if you have the same problem!

Comment: The answer from Daniel Roseman also works - its about the quotes - don't forget them ! ;)